# UIView Animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I need to flip my view horizontally.

I tried to flip along with the navigation Controller when i did this my background screen becomes black

How to avoid this?

I tried this code..

```
HomeViewController *homeVC = [[HomeViewController alloc] init];
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:homeVC];
nav.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[[self navigationController] presentViewController:nav animated:YES completion:^{
    [Constants showHomeScreenOnViewController:self];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code :-

```
UIViewController *controller = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIViewAnimationTransition trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: trans forView: [self window] cache: YES];
[navController presentModalViewController: controller animated: NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: You can change the type of animation by changing the value of trans variable

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid that black screen by changing your presentation style with below code,

Use this,

```
 nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
```

OR

```
 nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverCurrentContext;
```

Hope this will help you.